User terminology - dashboard?
I'd like to ask you about the appropriate terminology.
So, I'm preparing a Dashboard for clients, which will be a summary of their orders, invoices, requests, etc. - a classic stuff.
I'm wondering whether to use the word "Dashboard" in the menu, or perhaps "Summary"/"Overview" or something else?
Is the word "Dashboard" too technical and might not be very clear to the potential user, or do you think it's common enough to best convey what can be found there?
Thank you for your advice!

You say it's a menu item - is this going to be the default menu item? Because a lot of sites have a dashboard that they just call 'Home' in the navigation. They may use 'Dashboard' as the H1 or title on that page, but a simple 'Home' option in the navigation may be all you need.

Hey, thanks for reply. Dashboard will be on of the item in Account site, Home will be different, thats why I'm asking if the name is good for example for non-tech users?

"Dashboard" can mean many things, though I agree with the other poster that it should be clear, concise, and draw the user's attention to important information, especially outlier data, alerts, warnings, etc.
It is often used to refer to real-time information that is monitored to assess status and performance (like the actual dashboard in a car), but these days it can just as well mean an overview page that shows a specific user's chosen metrics so they can assess the status of their system at a glance.
If you are just presenting a screen full of tables, I am not sure it quite meets the description, but if you are providing an easy way for to user to make decisions, it's a dashboard.
In short, it should offer quick and easy visibility into information that will help in decision-making and problem remediation. If it does that, I think you are justified in calling it a dashboard.

I feel like I may have edited the tag on dashboard, or at least I kind of agree with the definition that's there:

"A dashboard is a design pattern or concept that focuses on the
display of data in a clear and concise way to draw the user's
attention to the most important information when making decisions. It
usually consists of one or more modules containing information from a
dataset arranged in a way to show their relationships to each other."

What you have there feels more like a summary or home page, although these days the terms are used pretty loosely and so you should probably check your client's understanding of the term.
I like to think of a dashboard as something that they look to when they need to make some decisions or need guidance on the actions that they need to take. If it is something that relates to normal business activities and is not very data-driven then you can consider using other terms.

It depends upon the context and target audience.
If the app is for wider audience than you should use "home" because it is the first screen when they log in to the system and they want to look at important information at a glance. Using the "Home" also makes it scaleable because you can add more things in future like

important notifications
reminders
notes they have made
Calendar and etc.
basically anything as per user preferences they can use it as a widget.

Secondly, if it is only numerical data that you have then the "Summary" would work
If the data is more context driven or has any specific parameter for example : if data is sorted as per the current data or week, then you can use "Date" or "Recents" or "Feed"
